# Combine company and contact arrays into single result ordered by third array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to create a combined `result` array comprised of company and contact entries.

The result array should have a company entry followed by their respective number of contact entries, as denoted by the `amount` array.

This is what I have already tried:

```
var company = [company1,company2,company3]
var contacts = [contact1,contact2,contact3,contact4,contact5,contact6]
var amount = [2,1,3]
var result = []

for (let i = 0; i < company.length; i++) {
   result.push(company[i])
  for (let x = 0; x < amount[i]; x++) {
    result.push(contacts[x])
  }
}

output = [{result}]
```

My expected output is:

```
result = [company1,contact1,contact2,company2,contact3,company3,contact4,contact5,contact6]
```

If I can create an array inside every company would be great.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve. It is not so clear. Please be specific...

Comment: Just add the amount of contacts to each company (the amount that every company have of contacts its on the array amount)

So company1 should have 2 contacts inside

Comment: @LeandroConti, I don't understand the last line of your question about an array inside every company. Could you please update your question to show how this should look?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very close.

You just need to account for the contacts that you've already pushed onto the result array when processing the contacts for the current company, rather than starting at the beginning of the list each time.

```js
var company = ['company1','company2','company3'];
var contacts = ['contact1','contact2','contact3','contact4','contact5','contact6'];
var amount = [2,1,3];
var result = [];
let c = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < company.length; i++) {
  result.push(company[i]);
  
  for (let j = 0; j < amount[i]; j++) {
    result.push(contacts[c]);
    c++;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```